# Copy and paste the complete row from one table to another table

Tags: vba, excel

I am  trying to select the complete row in `table1` and paste into `table5`.

Selected successfully but copy is missing.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long

    For I = 1 To ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(1).Range.Count - 1
        MsgBox (ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.Cells(I, 1))
        For J = 1 To ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(1).Range.Count - 1
            If ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.Cells(I, 1) = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").DataBodyRange.Cells(J, 1) Then
                ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").ListRows(J).Range.Select
                ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").ListRows(J).Range.Copy
                Worksheets("RECHNUNGS 1").Active
                ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table13").ListRows(J).Range.Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            End If
        Next J
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: So what is happening exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Try to isolate the not working code and make it work. Imagine you want to copy row 3 to row 10 from the left to the right table:

[image]

This is the minimal working code, that would do it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    With ActiveSheet
        .ListObjects("Table3").ListRows(3).Range.Copy
        .ListObjects("Table13").ListRows(10).Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

And then try to build upon it. As you see, it is using `.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` and not paste, because `.Paste` is a method of the Worksheet.

Consider this - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)